# relocating divs of an Html page using css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have HTML structure as shown below. I want to relocate the position of divs such that 'calc' div should move to 'region-content' div and should appear on the right end. Is it possible to achieve this using css? Can any one provide me some references to work on this using css, etc.

```
<div class='region-content'>
  <form id='responseform'>
    <div class='content '>
      <div class ='formulation '>
        <div class='qtext '>
          <div class='calc '></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does it look like / do now?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve the change in DOM structure with CSS. So, `calc` div can't be moved to `region-content` div. You need to do some javascript work for that.

However, styling it to appear where you want should be possible. Please provide your css code, if possible a jsfiddle, if this part is still troubling you.

Comment: Please find my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/YHeSQtg755aOKug856GI?p=preview. Just like I had <div class="info"> on the left (outside class="formulation"), similarly I want keep this 'calc' div on right  ((outside class="formulation"). So finally I will have 'info' (left), 'formulation' (center), 'calc' (right). I want to reduce the width of 'formulation' to 50 to 75% to now, so that on the right end I have space for calculator.

Comment: With the layout you have in place, I don't think even styling can achieve that. You can play around with floats but still it would need some layout changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

`.region-content { position: relative; }`

`.calc { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }`

Other then this you will also need to change parameter for width to make this possible. Since you just posted html structure and not content within it including respective css, this is how I can guess the solution for you.